# Does a reduced row echolon only have one solution?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

In general, when finding the reduced row echolon for a matrix, is there only one solution, even if there is no solution?

$$\begin{pmatrix}2&3&5\\ \:-2&-3&-3\end{pmatrix}$$

I got the following answer by hand (no solution because $1$ does not $= -2$):

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&0&-2\\ 0&1&1\end{pmatrix}$$

But an online calculator gave this answer (no solution because $0$ does not $= 2$):

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&1.5&2.5\\ \:0&0&2\end{pmatrix}$$

Is mine wrong or are they both correct?

Thank you

Comment: "no solution because $1$ does not $=−2$": and ?

Comment: That's all I had. If I was meant to have more, then that shows how much of a beginner I am. 

Not sure what the down vote was about (not saying it was you, Yves). I had my answer and I compared to an online calculator. Rather than shamelessly copying, I wanted to learn why mine was different. Egreg's answer solves the question if someone didn't know that's what they had to do. Only experienced mathematicians are allowed to ask questions?

Comment: My comment was a question. I can't figure out the relation you make between $1\ne-2$ and "no solution".

Comment: I think I might not understand the topic so well. I believed the first to columns are the arithmetic part of an equation, like "1 + 0" and the 3rd column was what the equation equaled. So I thought it was saying, $1+0=-2$

Comment: Sorry but you are forming obscure sentences. Another example is "is there only one solution, even if there is no solution?". The learning of mathematics is also about expressing things clearly and unambiguously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your row echelon form is wrong. The second column is a scalar multiple of the first, which means you cannot have a leading one in the second column, because elementary row operation don't change linear relations among columns.

In your matrix, the first two columns form a linearly independent set: this rules out that this matrix can be obtained from the given one by elementary row operations.

A row echelon form from your matrix is obtained by the operations
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 3 & 5 \\
-2 & -3 & 2
\end{pmatrix}
&\to
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 3/2 & 5/2 \\
-2 & -3 & 2
\end{pmatrix}
&& R_1\gets \tfrac{1}{2}R_1
\\&\to
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 3/2 & 5/2 \\
0 & 0 & 7
\end{pmatrix}
&&R_2\gets R_2+2R_1
\\&\to
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 3/2 & 5/2 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
&& R_2\gets\tfrac{1}{7}R_2
\\&\to
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 3/2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
&& R_1\gets R_1-\tfrac{5}{2}R_2
\end{align}
The last step produces the *reduced* row echelon form.

Comment: Thank you egreg. I did not know the bottom row had to be 0 with a 2x3 matrix

Comment: @Anon I'm not sure of what you mean with that. The bottom row in the row echelon form is what it is. A row in a row echelon matrix must starts with zeros below and left of the pivot in the previous line.

Answer (score 3):

Check this [website](http://www.math.odu.edu/~bogacki/cgi-bin/lat.cgi) out!

Following this step: $$\begin{pmatrix}1&1.5&2.5\\ \:0&0&2\end{pmatrix}$$

There are 2 steps. First, multiply the 2nd row by 0.5 to get: $$\begin{pmatrix}1&1.5&2.5\\ \:0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$

Then, add -2.5 times to the 2nd row to the 1st row  to get: $$\begin{pmatrix}1&1.5&0\\ \:0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$